# How to disable back,forward and Refresh functionality in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Can anyone help me to disable browser back,forward, back button and right click menu functionality using JavaScript or JQuery? I have tried disabling the back button like this:

```
function disableBackButton() {
     window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
```

I have called this function in the Body `onload` event. I have a doubt that where we need to put this code in the Calling page or Called Page.Suppose i have two pages like this `FirstPage.aspx` and `SecondPage.aspx`. When I navigate from the First Page to Second Page when I click back button of the browser it should not go to `FirstPage.aspx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [A Thorough Examination of "Disabling the Back Button."](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201700/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111500-1.shtml)

Comment: Ok.How can i do this from Server Side?Like Clearing the Cache Memory.

Comment: You can do like ... Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Comment: Where do i need to add this line s of Code ?Either in Calling page or Called Page ?

Comment: Called page, which you don't want cache the page.

Comment: Thanks i will try and Let you know